# React - Loading external script gives me error : Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document'

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to load an external script in the middle of my React Component.

```
import React from 'react';

class Test extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "http://example.com/form.js";
    this.myDiv.appendChild(script);
  }

  render() {
    return <div ref={e => (this.myDiv = e)} />;
  }
}
```

Unfortunately the external script contains `document.write`. Therefore it gives me an error when I try to load it :

```
Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.
```

The error is quite easy to understand. As the script is run after the document as been parsed, it cannot use `document.write`.

What are my options to remedy this problem ?

**What I did so far :**

So far I have tried using Krux's `postscribe` module but failed to make it work :

```
import React from 'react';

class Test extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div id="myDiv" />
        <script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: postscribe(
            "#myDiv",
            <script src="http://example.com/form.js" />
          )
        }} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

you can use "**react-async-script-loader**" npm module.

This module helps in lazy-loading scripts within component.

Or within React-component-lifecycle you can do something like this:

```
document.createElement('script');
        asyncScript.src = 'your script url';
        asyncScript.async = true;
        asyncScript.onload = () => {
          // The setTimeout lets us pretend that Stripe.js took a long time to load
          // Take it out of your production code!
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({
              stateVariable: **window.{your script exposed object}**
            });
          }, 500);
        };
```

Comment: thanks, this will also help. But I figured it out as seen above.